# Display a MS Access Report using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using VBA to assemble a report and display on-screen.

```
If Me.Frame15.Value = 1 Then
    DoCmd.openreport "Inspections due"
End If
```

When this is run, it sends the report to the printer, rather than displaying on screen. Is this due to a setting in the report, or an incorrect command?

Comment: That worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Access that you want to **view** the report. As you've found out, using `DoCmd.openreport` without any additional variables other than the form name attempts to print the form.

You can use acViewReport as per se:

`DoCmd.openreport "Inspections due", acViewReport`